# Proving $\bigcup \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{A})=\mathcal{A}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I'm working on operations on collections of sets and I've run aground.

I'm trying to prove that if $\mathcal{A}$ is a collection of sets $\mathcal{A}_i, i=1,2,...$, then 
$$\bigcup{\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{A})}=\mathcal{A}$$
But how do I write the notation for the power set of a collection of sets?  They are sets of sets, so $\{\mathcal{A}, \{\mathcal{A}_1\},...\{\mathcal{A}_1,\mathcal{A}_2\},...\}$... But how do I write that notationally?

Comment: What exactly is you notation? Usually
$$\cal P (\cal A) := \{ B : B\subset \cal A\}$$
($B\subset\cal A$ is also seen as $B\subseteq \cal A$)

Comment: Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/title-and-latex).

Comment: Sorry....  I didn't know that.

Comment: @Iceman No problem, that's why I told you :).

Comment: I changed the wording.  I already have indexed notation for the original collection of sets so how would I notate the power set of a collection of sets?

Comment: By the way, I can show this for small examples.  It's the generalized identity I'm trying to figure out...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. For any $a\in A$, we have $a\in \{a\}\subseteq A$; hence $a\in \bigcup \mathcal{P}(A)$.
2. For any $a\in \bigcup \mathcal{P}(A)$, there is some $B\in \mathcal{P}(A)$ with $a\in B$.  But then $a\in B\subseteq A$, so $a\in A$.

The nature of the elements of $A$ are irrelevant; in your case they happen to be sets but it doesn't matter.

Comment: Is $a$ in the collection of sets, i mean, is $a$ a set or an element of a set in $\mathcal{A}$?

Comment: $a$ is an element of $A$.  Since $A$ is a collection of sets, $a$ is itself a set.

Comment: Okay.  I have never seen a set written in lowercase letters so I was confused.  But I see the point you are making.  The elements of the set are inconsequential in type...  A set of sets with sets as elements is still only a set and can be treated as such.  It feels weird at first but I'll get used to it.

Answer (score 3):

You can write
$${\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{A})} = \{ {\mathcal X} \mid {\mathcal X} \subseteq {\mathcal A}\},$$
so
$$\bigcup\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{A}) = \bigcup_{{\mathcal X} \subseteq {\mathcal A}} {\mathcal X}.$$
Note that it doesn't matter that ${\mathcal A}$ is a set of *sets*; you neither need that for the definition of ${\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{A})}$, nor for the proof of $\bigcup{\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{A})} = {\mathcal A}$.

Comment: So I wouldn't need then since $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{A})=\{\mathcal{X}|\mathcal{X}\subseteq\mathcal{A}\}$, then $\bigcup{\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{A})}=\bigcup{\{\mathcal{X}|{\mathcal{X}}\subseteq{\mathcal{A}\}}}$ in a proof?

Comment: If you mean that you don't need any details about the elements of ${\mathcal A}$, then yes. Note that you're never taking a union of members of ${\mathcal A}$, just of subsets of ${\mathcal A}$.

Comment: And if you wanted to go in more detail $\bigcup \{ {\mathcal X} \mid {\mathcal X} \subseteq {\mathcal A} \} = \{ x \mid \exists {\mathcal X} \subseteq {\mathcal A} [ x \in {\mathcal X} ] \}$.